# Getting compilation error with makefile

Tags: c, unix

I tried the following example program to understand the usage of the makefiles in compilation.

### main.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<functions.h>
int main()
{
 print_hello();
 printf("\nThe Factorial is : %d\n",factorial(5));
 return 0;
}
```

### hello.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<functions.h>
void print_hello()
{
 printf("\nHello world!\n");
}
```

### factorial.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<functions.h>
void factorial(int n)
{
 if(n!=1){
  return(n*factorial(n-1));
 }
 else
  return 1;
}
```

### functions.h

```
#include<stdio.h>
void print_hello();
int factorial(int n);
```

### makefile

```
exec : ./compile

compile : main.o hello.o factorial.o
  gcc -o compile

main.o : main.c functions.h
  gcc -c main.c

hello.o : hello.c functions.h
  gcc -c hello.c

factorial.o : factorial.c functions.h
  gcc -c factorial.c
```

Error :

```
cheetah@desktop:~/make_example$ make compile
gcc -c main.c
main.c:2:22: error: functions.h: No such file or directory
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
cheetah@desktop:~/make_example$
```

EDITED:

```
gcc -c main.c
gcc -c hello.c
gcc -c factorial.c
gcc -o compile
gcc: no input files
make: *** [compile] Error 1
```

Please help me understand why is it throwing an error as functions.h not found as I have included it in my makefile.

Comment: Note that `functions.h` does not give a prototype for `print_hello()`; it just declares the function as taking an indeterminate (but fixed) number of arguments.  To be a prototype in C, you must give `void print_hello(void);` (though in C++, this would all be different).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative to changing the source, you can include the current directory for header file lookup using [`-I`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options) option of gcc. In that case your `makefile` rule where you need the header file will look like as follows (assuming the header file is the current directory):

```
main.o : main.c functions.h
  gcc -c main.c -I./
```

Again as already pointed out, the error you were facing later during linking was due to missing input files in the `compile` target. For this again there is alternative. You can make use of `$^` in the makefile for all you depencies. In which you `compile` rule will look like:

```
compile:main.o hello.o factorial.o
    gcc -o compile $^
```

See this [link](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/makefiles_continued.html) for some information regarding makefile macros.
Side notes:

1. [Guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) are missing your header file
2. There is mismatch in declaration & definition of `factorial` function.
3. As already mentioned by Jonathan Leffler be adviced about the prototype of `print_hello`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
#include<functions.h>
```

with

```
#include"functions.h"
```

A detailed explanation is here: http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/3379

And finally, object files are missing at the linking stage.

```
compile : main.o hello.o factorial.o
  gcc -o compile main.o hello.o factorial.o
```

Comment: If I read it correctly, that article only explains that the two styles of inclusion search locations in different orders. Does that explain why the first one doesn't end up finding `functions.h`, assuming it's in the current directory?

Comment: Thanks . Now i'm getting error as no i/p files.. dunno what i missed to include

Comment: Why remove functions.h from the makefile - it should be in the dependency list for building the object file.

Comment: @DanFego Because, I suppose, the `functions.h` doesn't locate in the default search location.  And generally, the dubbed *default search location* is usually your **standard system include directory**.

Comment: @AdrianCornish Header files are needed at the compile stage, and are included in `*.c` files.  They have nothing to do with dependencies.

Comment: He means the .c files depend on the .h files during compile time.

Comment: @tangrs Inclusion of header files are done in `*.c` files.  It's unnecessary and redundant to put them in makefile.

Comment: @shinkou What if you define a struct in a header, then at some time change its definition so that it takes more/less space. If the object files depend on the proper headers, everything gets recompiled as necessary. If they don't and you change some source files including the changed header but not others, only the changed files get recompiled, resulting in breakage.

Comment: Thank u all for helping me to understand the problem.

Comment: @DanielFischer You're right.  I've been forgoing object code level integrity with ease of maintenance since I usually simply delete all object files (`make clean`) whenever I make radical changes. I admit this may not be a good practice.  I have my answer edited.  +1 for pointing that out.